# Understanding Sha through $K_2$

Tags: algebraic-k-theory, brauer-groups, tate-shafarevich-groups

Consider the following setup, to keep things easy:  let $F$ be a number field with ring of integers $A$.  Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $F$ with Neron model $N$ over $A$.  Let $Sha(E)$ be the usual Tate-Shafarevich group of $E$ -- that nice group that everyone hopes is finite.

It's known (Artin and Grothendieck) that $Sha(E)$ is closely related to the Brauer group $Br(N)$, and in particular one is finite if and only if the other is finite.  And this Brauer group can be identified with the kernel of localization:
$$Br(N) \cong Ker \left( Br(E) \rightarrow \bigoplus_v Br(E_v) \right)$$

The Brauer groups on the right side can be related to (unramified) Brauer groups of function fields, i.e.,
$$Br(E) \cong Br_{nr}( F(E) ), \quad Br(E_v) \cong Br_{nr}( F_v(E) ),$$
So really, finiteness of Sha is related to finiteness of some subgroup of $Br(F(E))$ -- the kernel of some big localization map.

**Question 1:**  Is this written down somewhere?  I can probably glue together the literature, but I imagine someone else has done this already, relating Sha to the Brauer group of the function field $F(E)$.  And of course, it should generalize to smooth projective curves in some nice way.

What I'm more interested in is the connection to $K_2$ of fields.  The Galois symbol will give a surjective map from $K_2( F(E))$ to the $n$-torsion in the Brauer group $Br( F(E))[n]$, for every $n$.  So in this way, every element of $Br(F(E))$ arises from some combination of Steinberg symbols $\{ \alpha_1, \beta_1\} \cdots \{ \alpha_t, \beta_t \} \in K_2(F(E))$

**Question 2:**  Is the finiteness of $Sha(E)$ equivalent to the finiteness of the kernel of some localization map whose source is $K_2(F(E))$?

Finally, here's the motivation for my curiosity, and one more question.  Some of the difficulty in understanding $Sha(E)$ seems related to the fact that we don't have a uniform way of writing down elements of $Sha(E)$ (without assuming its finiteness).  Geometrically, $n$-torsion elements of $Sha(E)$ might be describable as genus one curves embedded in $P^N$ (with $N \approx n$?), but that's not so uniform since $N$ could be large, a priori.  Compare this to the fact that every ideal in the ring of integers in a number field can be generated by two elements, giving a sort of bounded method of description.

**Question 3:** In this spirit, do we know that elements of $K_2(F(E))$ (maybe under some local condition) have bounded symbol length, e.g., that every element can be expressed as the product of no more than $t$ Steinberg symbols?  For some smallish $t$?